# Blocked at google's two-step verification

Tags: python-2.7, firefox, selenium-webdriver

So the story goes that I had a perfectly working script for the past week or so, it would log in to google (by loading a certain firefox profile - which allowed me to skip 2 -step verification), scrape some data from the company site (which needs google login to access), save to csv and quit. This would occur hourly for analysis.

Alas, alack, the issue arose this morning where instead of logging in directly, the two-step verification is appearing, even though the script has not changed at all. I cannot program to enter username+password, because it sends a text to my phone with a verification code after this... 
I'm absolutely at a loss. I thought loading the firefox profile would avoid this problem (and it did for ~ 5 days). Can you help me?

I am using Python 2.7, Selenium & Mac OSX

Comment: can't you disable 2-step verification through the google settings?

Comment: I guess there is an option to add a particular machine as a trusted device under google settings so that 2 step verification screen doesn't show up only when you login through that specific machine.

Comment: Google has disallowed disabling two-step for this account (it's under a company domain). And I've already allowed trusted device but this doesn't work either... quite a pickle